# AngularJS how to store client-side only info on a $resource instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out "the right way" to store client-side-only state for an instance of a resource.

Suppose I have an ng-resource, `Blerg` which has only one data field, "name" and [per the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#credit-card-resource), I do something like

```
var blergInstance = new Blerg();
blergInstance.name = "Frankie";
blergInstance.$save();
```

This results in an http POST to the resource URL with json `{name: "Frankie"}`.  Ok, great.

But I actually need to pass that `blergInstance` around my client-side application interface for a while, and I want to store some state about that `blergInstance` to tell the client-side application how to display it or how to interact with it.  E.g. I've got a directive that wants to optionally display to the user that "**Your blergInstance hasn't been saved yet**".  Or I've got a button elsewhere that will "**Moog this Blerg**", and I only want to allow a Blerg to be Mooged *once* before saving.

My first (admittedly naive) approach would be to do something like

```
var blergInstance = new Blerg();
blergInstance.name = "Frankie";
blergInstance.saved = false //
blergInstance.hasBeenMooged = false // 
// pass the blergInstance around to other services, directives, etc
blergInstance.$save();
```

But now the http POST looks like `{name: "Frankie", saved: false, hasBeenMooged: false}`.

So how should I attach "state" to the resource instance that is only relevant to the client-side, and which should not be sent to the server?

Comment: Why shouldn't you wrap the *resource* and state into an simple object and pass around, where *resource* will have the necessary properties only.

Comment: @code-jaff that sounds like a promising approach - if you could turn that comment into an answer i could award you some magic points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't you wrap the *resource* and *state* into an simple object and pass around, where resource will have the necessary properties only

```
var stateful = {};
var blergInstance = new Blerg();
blergInstance.name = "Frankie";

stateful.resource = blergInstance;
stateful.saved = false;
stateful.hasBeenMooged = false;

// pass the blergInstance around to other services, directives, etc
stateful.resource.$save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to code-jaff's solution

Warning: coffeescript ahead

**Step 1:** 
Create a service with all your API calls

```
app.service 'Api', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
    {
        Blerg: $resource "/api/v1/blerg/:id", {id: "@id"}
        ....
    }
]
```

**Step 2:**
Call your Api service and pass in an explicit object

```
app.controller 'Ctrl', (Api) ->
    saveBlerg = {}
    saveBlerg.name = Blerg.name
    Api.Blerg.save(saveBlerg)
```